# Customizing Top Suite bar in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding, 2016

Has anyone done any customization for top navigation bar in SharePoint 2016?

I have tried quite a few of the articles written for 2013, but I have been unable to do this.

I would like to do it in custom master page rather than powershell

Any link of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sharepoint 16, they give more powershell control for top suit's bar, I.e changing the logo, text etc

If that is what you looking for then check this

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx

Comment: thanks for reply Waqas, But i would like to do it in my custom Masterpage

Comment: Custom master pages are now very much discouraged and have been for a year or more. In particular, if you ever want to move to Office 365 you will certainly have issues due to the pace of change, especially around the new layouts. These will come to on-prem versions within a year or so I would anticipate.